# como ocultar una ventana de tkinter con thread?

Tags: python, tkinter

He estado intentando hacer un programa en python utilizando la libreria tkinter, que simule un programa con login y abra otra ventana.

La idea es ocultar la ventana de login y lo logre con threads, pero me arroja el **siguiente error**:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yeison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\yeison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'ventana_2' object is not callable
[Finished in 265.3s]
```

aca el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as m
from tkinter import messagebox


import threading

class logeo():
    def __init__(self,ventana):
        self.raiz=ventana
        self.raiz.geometry("250x200")
        self.raiz.title("Login")
        self.raiz.config(bg="white")


        # constructor de fuentes************************
        titulos = Font(family="inherit", size=12)
        labels = Font(family="inherit", size=10)
        boton = Font(family="inherit", size=10)
        parrafos = Font(family="Berlin Sans FB", size=11)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.raiz)
        self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.notebook.config(width=235, height=165)
        self.pes0 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.pes0, text="Credenciales")



        usuario_label = Label(self.pes0, text="Usuario: ", font=labels).place(x=5,y=5)
        self.usuario = Entry(self.pes0)
        self.usuario.place(x=95,y=5)
        self.usuario.configure(bg="#FFFFFF",width=20)
        self.usuario.focus()

        clave_label = Label(self.pes0, text="Contraseña: ", font=labels).place(x=5,y=30)
        self.clave = Entry(self.pes0,show="*")
        self.clave.place(x=95,y=30)
        self.clave.configure(bg="#FFFFFF",width=20)

        self.boton_ejecutar=Button(self.pes0,text="Ejecutar",bg="#5BC500",width=14,fg="white",font=boton,height=1,command=self.run)
        self.boton_ejecutar.place(x=5,y=120)
        self.boton_salir=Button(self.pes0,text="Salir",bg="#5BC500",width=14,fg="white",font=boton,height=1,command=self.salir)
        self.boton_salir.place(x=110,y=120)


    def validar(self):
        return self.usuario.get() !="" and self.clave.get() !=""


    def run(self):
        print(self.usuario.get())
        print(self.clave.get())

        if self.validar():
            global ventana2 
            #ventana_login = Toplevel(ventana_2())
            ventana.destroy()
            ventana2=Tk()
            my_thread = threading.Thread(target=ventana_2(ventana2))
            my_thread.start()
            
        else:
            print("producto vacio")


    def salir(self):
        ventana.destroy()

    def cerrar_ventana_1(self):
        logeo.destroy()

class ventana_2():
    def __init__(self,ventana):
        self.raiz=ventana
        self.raiz.geometry("500x200")
        self.raiz.title("Greta")
        self.raiz.config(bg="white")

        # constructor de fuentes************************
        titulos = Font(family="inherit", size=12)
        labels = Font(family="inherit", size=10)
        boton = Font(family="inherit", size=10)
        parrafos = Font(family="Berlin Sans FB", size=11)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.raiz)
        self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.notebook.config(width=235, height=165)
        self.pes0 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        
        self.notebook.add(self.pes0, text="ventana")

        self.pes0 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.pes0, text="ventana2")


def main():
    global ventana 
    ventana=Tk()
    aplicacion=logeo(ventana)
    ventana.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No puedes crear un Thread instanciando una clase... Tiene que ser a una función (un `def`, no una `class`). Puedes intentar hacer una función que te cree la `ventana2`... Pero de todas formas me parece que hay problemas por la forma que has construido tu código...

Comment: hola, intente utilizar el toplevel pero este me dejaba la ventana de logueo visible, sabe usted como seria una mejor forma de optimizar el codigo?

Comment: A lo mejor puedes usar un toplevel y en lugar de destruir el Tk principal lo escondes (`.hide()` en lugar de `.destroy()`)

Answer (score 0):

El *target* de un *Thread* debe ser una función, de modo que en principio tendrías que sustituir:

```py
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=ventana_2(ventana2))
```

Por esto otro:

```py
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda:ventana_2(ventana2))
```

Sin embargo, ahora se arrojará el siguiente error: `main thread is not in main loop`

**Tienes que reestructurar tu código, no necesitas *Threads***. Para simplificar voy a crear un pequeño ejemplo:

```py
from tkinter import *


class App1(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.ok = False

        self.title('App1 - ¿continuar?')
        self.geometry('320x240')

        self.btn_cancel = Button(self, text='CANCELAR', command=self.destroy)
        self.btn_continue = Button(self, text='CONTINUAR', command=self.continuar)

        self.btn_cancel.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.btn_continue.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.mainloop()

    def continuar(self):
        self.ok = True
        self.destroy()



class App2(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title('App2 - Aplicación principal')
        self.geometry('320x240')

        self.label = Label(self, text='HOLA MUNDO')
        self.label.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.mainloop()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app1 = App1()

    if app1.ok:
        App2()
```

En este ejemplo he creado dos clases que heredan de `Tk`: `App1` y `App2`

La clase `App1` tiene un atributo `ok` que se inicializa en el método `App1.__init__` así:

```py
self.ok = False
```

Tiene, además, dos botones: `self.btn_cancel` y `self.btn_continue`

Si se hace click en `btn_cancel` el formulario se cierra y `ok == False`:

```py
self.btn_cancel = Button(self, text='CANCELAR', command=self.destroy)
```

Pero si se hace click en `btn_continue` se ejecuta el método `continuar`:

```py
self.btn_continue = Button(self, text='CONTINUAR', command=self.continuar)
```

El método `continuar` asigna `self.ok = True` y cierra el formulario:

```py
def continuar(self):
    self.ok = True
    self.destroy()
```

Al instanciar `App1`:

```py
app1 = App1()
```

**El programa no ejecutará la siguiente línea de código hasta que se cierre el formulario, y la siguiente línea de código puede ser una condición que evalue a `app1.ok`:**

```py
app1 = App1()

if app1.ok:
    App2()
```

En lugar de utilizar `app1.ok` podría hacerse lo mismo con una variable global.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de resolverlo, que tal vez no es la más elegante pero funciona, es quitarle el manejador al login y en el evento de cierre de la ventana secundaria (la que abrís
con topLevel luego del login) destruir la del login, cerrando así por completo la aplicación.

```
ventanaPantallaPrincipal(self._vtn_inicioSesion)
self._vtn_inicioSesion.overrideredirect(True)
```

Luego en el evento de cierre de la ventana que se abrio desde el login:

```
self._vtn_pantallaPrincipal.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.manejadorCierreVentana)

def manejadorCierreVentana(self):
        self.registrarCierreDeSesion()
        self._vtnInicioSesion.destroy()
```